# Comment color based on keyword in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm has a feature that colors your comments yellow if they include `TODO` or `FIXME` keywords. What is the way to add more keywords to the list and change the colors based on the keyword?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PyCharm:

1. Press `CTRL+ALT+S` or navigate to `Preferences/Settings`
2. Search `TODO` or go to `Editor/TODO`
3. Add a pattern using the + button. For example, the pattern for `ERROR` keyword would be `\berror\b.*`. It can also be any other regex pattern.
   `\b`  - word boundaries; `.*` - zero or more characters.
4. Unselect `Use color scheme TODO default colors` and change the foreground color (ex. `C00000` - red)
5. Press OK and Apply

Results:

[image: Results]

Settings:

[image: Settings]

Example `ERROR` pattern (red):

[image: Pattern]